# GRANT VIEW DEFINITION on DATABASE_ROLE SCHEMA but not in DATABASE_ROLE. Does not let me open table definition of the SCHEMA I granted

Tags: azure-sql-database

```
CREATE ROLE rolename

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO rolename
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO rolename
GRANT CREATE FUNCTION TO rolename
GRANT CREATE SCHEMA TO rolename
GRANT CREATE DEFAULT TO rolename

GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA :: schemaname  TO  rolename;
```

Then "Open Table Definition" gives:

> Could not retrieve the definition of schemaname.table from the server

If I do

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO rolename
```

then I can see all schema's tables, views etc. definitions.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: How can I Open Table Definition by only Granting View Definition to schema? I can see The list of the table in the Server Explorer of the schema I just grant. But cannot open it to see the design

Answer (score 0):

The VIEW DEFINITION permission on a given schema is not enough for the database principal to view the definition of the tables inside this schema. To make the definition of tables accessible, use [object permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql).